# Уровни иерархии БД

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, laravel, архитектура

Тут 5 уровней БД
[image: Тут 5 уровней БД]

Тут 3 уровня верно? уровень это максимальная вложенность в бд ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так считать неправильно?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И последний момент.

Как правильно связать пользователя с должностью, отношение 1 к 1, с условием что юезр в одной таблице, должности в другой таблице.

Использовать pivot таблицу ?

Но она ведь предназначена для отношения многие ко многим

На второй картинке я использую такой подход но он правильный или нет?

Спасибо

Comment: Откуда вы взяли такое понятие как "уровень иерархии" и для чего вообще их считать ? (тем более что это не всегда возможно при циклических связях). Про пользователя и должность смотря по целевой задаче. Если у пользователя есть только одна должность, то в самой таблице пользователей хранится id должности и это связь 1 ко многим. Если пользователь может занимать одновременно несколько должностей, то отдельная таблица "пользователь-должность" (многие-ко-многим). И еще похожие на последний варианты если должность одна, но в определенный момент времени

Comment: А связи 1к1 это когда у вас может быть только по одному пользователю, занимающему каждую уникальную должность. Это редко используемый вид связи, так как обычно проще положить данные в одну запись, чем делать две таблицы с такой связью

Comment: задание, создать бд с 5 уровнями иерархии, сложно ее сделать когда не знаешь как считать)

Спасибо большое, я в общем неправильно понимал связи.